# Github - Download Not Fully Included All Folders/Files

Tags: github, phpoffice

I am new to Github. I downloaded the PHPWord (link below) on Github, but some how the folders: samples, tests, docs are missing.  It only has the folder "src/PhpWord".

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

I also use `composer require phpoffice/phpword` and the result is the same (missing folders)

Am I doing something wrong or there is another way to download which will include the other folders: samples, tests, docs.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the other folders are missing may be due to you downloaded the Zip file and not a clone to your PC which downloads everything including the source code.

The Zip download only contains one file folder to the program. I suspect this is the finished product rather than the development product your seeing in the GitHub repository. Although, usually the author of the program includes this in the instructions which I didn't see when reading them.

You may also want to re-read the instructions on the REAME.md document in the repository. There are some requirements that need to be preformed before using composer to install the dependencies. It may account for  the "missing folders" message

Comment: I downloaded the GitHub desktop and cloned it.  Now I see those folders.  Thank you so much!